# How to turn off a Mac Laptop's "I'm alive" breathing light?

Tags: macos, mac

My Mac laptop is great but when I close the lid, there is this light alternating between 0 and 1 and I don't like it.

Can I turn it off, somehow? It annoys me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to turn it off unfortunately.

Some options:

- Put a bit of tape over it
- Use [InsomniaX](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/22211) so your laptop doesn't really go to sleep when you close it
- You could also open it up and disconnect the LED wire ( **not recommended** )

Comment: so i am going to have to turn it off now then... would have loved to let it running and do stuff silently while i sleep...

Comment: You can, use InsomniaX as suggested :)

Comment: Closing a mac laptop without letting it go to sleep is _very_ bad. The case is especially built so that the heat can escape the laptop. This also causes a heavy hit on battery life.

Comment: "Putting tape over it???" - Imagine what Steve Jobs would do to me if he saw me with tape on a Mac? At least he would sew me really bad! ;-)

Comment: Haha! I don't know, I do anything I can for a peaceful nights sleep. If it means putting tape over LEDs, consider it done! :)

Comment: Just put a book in front of it so you can't see it at night?