# Powerbook Sleep Light?

Tags: macos, sleep, osx-leopard, powerbook

I have a 17 inch Powerbook G4 with Mac OS 10.5.8 and I always keep it on sleep when I'm  not using it. However, the little light on the front of the Powerbook that pulsates while in sleep mode prevents me from sleeping. I recently found out about this one trick though when you press Option-Command-Eject, the light is significantly dimmer. I would be happy although, When I close the screen of the Powerbook, the light turns bright again. Could anyone help me keep the light dim when the lid is closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This same question was asked [recently](https://superuser.com/questions/90273/how-to-turn-off-a-mac-laptops-im-alive-breathing-light).

Maybe he was talking of different hardware, but [John T](https://superuser.com/users/1931/john-t) said there's no built-in way.

I liked his 'put some tape over it' suggestion.

Comment: I wanted something that could be done via software, that's why I aksed this question. But it looks like neither Superuser nor Google helped me on this one. Oh well, looks like I'm going to have to deal with it. Maybe if it stays on enough, it will burn out and I will be happy :D

Comment: They would have used an LED, so it's not likely to burn out, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Put some object in front of it?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⏏</kbd> is just a shortcut to put the computer to sleep. It's no different from chosing `Sleep` from the Apple menu.

You're noticing that when the computer is open, it uses ambient light sensors to monitor the room and dim the light if the room is dark. When you close the computer, the light sensors are disabled and the light stays at full brightness.

So, if you like the dimmer light better, just leave the computer open after putting it to sleep.

I don't know of a way to disable the sleep light in software.